# What causes a theme to be inefficient?

Tags: theme-development, optimization

Someone has asked me to analyze if his theme is 'good'. I've decided to analyze it in terms of

1. number of assets that the theme needs
2. compressing those assets
3. ensuring wp_enqueue_x is being used
4. ensure that loops are properly coded

Am I missing anything important and obvious? I'd love to know what else you may think of, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - "good" is a bit vague a term.. Good for what ?? IF you mean technically valid , there are SOOOO many items to check, that you can fill a whole website with it . Those items also depend on personal preferences and are not always objective AND are changing with time .
If you mean "efficient" as in resource efficient for server side , that would include the analyzing of each php function markup and execution order.
If you mean "efficient" for client-side loading , there are more than 100 variables that can effect that , inluding but not limited to : kind of font used (and not only number ) compression of data and scripts, reducing http requests with sprites and combined JS . optimizing the JS - loading resources from cdn - mirroring resources ,clouding , caching and on and on ..

In shorts , I can start listing here the "obvious" like , Valid csS and XHTML , Html-5 ready , Full page templates, full sprites, Loading from CDN, support for munues, custom-images or all new features ,etc. etc. I can also refer you to each of the items here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development_Checklist or here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test , or many other "checklists" that you will find in google .. But like I said, the term "good" is not so objective , and the to-do list will probably have 1000 items on it .

BTW - there are even some plugins that perform some tests on your theme - like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-test-drive/ . in shorts - IMHO  this question is just too enormous to answer .

Comment: Thanks @krembo99 for taking the time to write up a detailed answer. I agree that the scope is super wide. Your suggestions are exactly what I was looking for and have provided me some excellent starting points for which to approach the project.

Comment: Well, than a small voting up would help to mark the question as answered. ..

Comment: I don't have enough privileges yet, but will remember to come back to this question when I do :)

Comment: well, just click the small "v" icon.